# Slow Debugging and Development with Asp.Net MVC projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, debugging, iis, startup

There is an MVC project that uses different class libraries and WCF services. Actually there are 228 assemblies in the bin directory. When I start to debug in local IIS, IIS tries to warm up and load all assemblies. This takes very long time. So everytime I have to wait for a long time when I built the project. So, is there any workaround when debuging and testing in the local environment? Is there any solution to speed up the startup process for debugging? The big web sites like stackoverflow, how can you debug in a big framework?

Comment: Why would you have so many assemblies in the first place?  I seriously doubt even stackoverflow has anywhere near 643 assemblies.

Comment: fm - 643 projects in one deployable! - That's just crazy

Comment: Whoops sorry, I had looked the all files in the bin directory. There are actually 228. I'm editing the question.

Comment: Even 228 is ridonkulous.

Comment: I can't do anything about it. This is a big solution, and there are several inner projects.

Comment: Then suffer for the lousy architecture. What are they? single class assemblies? :)

Comment: @jgauffin :) There are many people, different teams, different companies working on this project. So if every company and and team adds a few assembly to this project, you have a lot of assembly in total.